# Using instrumental portion of copyrighted song?

Tags: copyright

I have [this](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/02VySrVYFTnAPmQYDj-h97twQ#Intro_song) portion of Monsoon Br.eakfast.

I’m planning to use it for an creepy intro animation

I know that it is copyrighted, yet I have seen other people use it without the lyrics, and it seems like it isn’t copyrighted if you don’t use the lyrics.

Like this[image]

According to what I circled, apparently it’s ok to mute the music and bypass copyright.

But is it really? I need to know before I get in trouble with the law…

Comment: The fact that a random person on the internet does something does not mean it is legal. Nor is it a defense.

Answer (score 5):

No, it isn't.

A sound recording of a song has a few different elements that are distinct from one another, but they are each protected by copyright (unless the song is old enough to have passed into the public domain):

- the lyrics
- the melody and other aspects of the musical composition
- the instrumental arrangement
- the recording itself

A sound recording is protected by copyright even if it is a recording of something that isn't protected by copyright.  If you use a portion of the recording that has no lyrics, or if you use technical means to suppress the lyrics or filter them out, you still have to contend with the copyright protection of the other elements.

But sometimes it *is* allowed to use copyright-protected material.  There is a lot of discussion about "fair use" and other circumstances under which one can use copyright-protected material without permission.  The most clear-cut way to use copyright-protected material without violating copyright, however, is to *have permission* in the form of a license.  You can always ask.

Comment: So is my portion copyrighted or not?

Comment: @Coder2195 what do you mean by "your portion"?  The link under "this" points to a file that I cannot open.

Comment: I put a link to the portion I’m going to use for my animation https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/02VySrVYFTnAPmQYDj-h97twQ#Intro_song

Comment: @Coder2195 ok, that link works.  Why do you think that portion wouldn't be protected by copyright?

Comment: Because someone used it without getting in trouble https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCpB9BemWhuVygQtJinCKzSA

Comment: @Coder2195 I once saw someone snatch a candy bar from a newsstand on a crowded subway platform before hopping on a subway train, thereby escaping any likelihood of getting in trouble.  Does that mean it's allowed?  No.  Besides, it's entirely possible that the use in the YouTube video is covered by a license (you linked to a channel; which video is it?).

Comment: It’s the music in her intro https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=inlw-F_dmuE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128779/discussion-between-coder2195-and-phoog).

Comment: @Coder2195 everything about it is copyrighted, certainly not just the lyrics.